# Which function family do ROC curves belong to?

Tags: functions

ROC curves are monotonically increasing functions $[0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ which start in (0, 0) and end in (1, 1). They are "over" the diagonal $x$.

They look a bit like $1/x$, but moved to the upper left and always above $x$.

Is there a parametrized form for such functions?

### Background

I want to make a small explanation of those. This is what I have so far ([code](https://github.com/MartinThoma/algorithms/blob/master/visualizations/xkcd-roc-curve/main.py)):

[image]

Comment: You can use $x^\alpha$ with $0\le \alpha \le 1$

Comment: @N74 Nice! I think I would accept that as an answer. It would be even better if I could specify a point $(0, 1) \times (0, 1)$ through which the function went in a smooth way

Comment: As $y=x^\alpha$, $\alpha={\ln y_0 \over \ln x_0}$ where the point you want to pass through is $(x_0, y_0)$

Comment: Nice! Should I make a community wiki answer or do you want to make an answer?

Comment: By the way, here is it on Wikipedia: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Roc-draft-xkcd-style.svg